# Controller does not recieve data from jsp page

Tags: ajax, spring-mvc, jsp, request-mapping, path-variables

I have sent data from jsp page to controller. It shows error.

> The origin server did not find a current representation for the target
>   resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

This is my controller::::

```
@GetMapping(value = "/createdistrict")
    public ModelAndView  createdistrict(Locale locale, Model model) {

        List<Division> allDivisionList = new ArrayList<Division>();
        allDivisionList = this.districtService.listdivisions() ;
        Map<Integer,String> allDivision = new LinkedHashMap<Integer,String>();

        for( int i=0 ; i < allDivisionList.size() ; i++) {

            //System.out.println(" division id ::::::::::" + allDivisionList.get(i).getId() + " division name:::::::::" + allDivisionList.get(i).getName());
            allDivision.put(allDivisionList.get(i).getId() , allDivisionList.get(i).getName());
        }
        return new ModelAndView("createdistrict" , "allDivision" , allDivision);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/adddistrict/{division}")
     public String addDistrict(@ModelAttribute("district")District district, ModelMap model ,@RequestParam("division") int division) {

        System.out.println("id:::::::::::::::::::" + division);
        this.districtService.adddistrict(district, division);
                return "redirect:districtlist";
    }
```

This is my jsp page::::

```
 <form method="POST" action="/farmvill/adddistrict" modelAtribute="district">
                <table class="create-table table table-hover">
                 <tr>
                    <td>
                        Division 
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    <select id="division" name="division">
                          <c:forEach items="${allDivision}" var="allDivision">
                          <option class="dropdivision" value="${allDivision.key}">${allDivision.value }</option>
                          </c:forEach>
                    </select> 
                    </td> 
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>
                        Name
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" path="name"></input>
                    </td> 
                  </tr>
                  <!-- End of single tr -->

                </table>
                <!-- End of table -->
                <div class="button-set text-right">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn site-btn filled-btn" id="savebutton">save</button>
                  <a href="" class="btn site-btn filled-btn">cancel</a>
                  <a href="" class="btn site-btn filled-btn">reset</a>
                </div>
                <!-- End of button-set -->
             </form>
```

What I should do now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `division` from mapping path. it's a regular request parameter

```
@RequestMapping(value="/adddistrict")
 public String addDistrict(@ModelAttribute("district")District district, ModelMap model ,@RequestParam("division") int division) {
```